alternatives to raisebox
When I use raisebox I usually get compiling errors even when it does exactly what I want it to do on the page.  Is there an alternative command that does the same thing and is more compiler-friendly, even if my code isn't optimal (i.e. I'm not a professional at it so it may not be optimally efficient or have some older-style syntax)?  (I'm using the book class.)

Better show what problems you face with \raisebox. Otherwise alternative solutions might have the same problems. These problems might even be solvable with \raisebox and you don't need an alternative.

Show what you are doing. Otherwise we have no idea what you are doing and we are all out of crystal balls. My guess you're doing something with math? (do remember that content argument of \raisebox is treated as text even in math mode)

Some times, alignment problem will come when use \raisebox, for those occurrence, use \smash along with raisebox, i.e., \smash{\raisebox{.}{..}}, but per @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz comment, better to provide the exact problem what are suffering

\raisebox is a core latex command. You will only get errors if you use it incorrectly. How can anyone suggest another comamnd that will not give errors even if used incorrectly?

I would strongly suggest that you show a compilable example of what you are doing and where the use of \raisebox does not work. In fact it is a very stable command and should almost never pose any problem.

The original raisebox and two examples of variations:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}


% Start the document
\begin{document}

% Create a new 1st level heading
\section{Main Heading}

A text \raisebox{1ex}{raised} here.

A text \textsuperscript{raised} here 

$\text{A text} \stackrel{\text{raised}}{\text{normal}} \text{here}$

\end{document}



your comment % Allow the usage of UTF-8 characters is misleading and/or wrong, it appears to imply that mathtools is related to input encoding, also all three of the \\  here are wrong and generate warnings on the terminal.

Thanks.  With raisebox I can lower something by making the distance negative, for this is there something like \textsubscript that does the same thing?  (I'm trying to lower something).

Also, is there an option specifically for use in math mode?

Code edited____

@Nate: Are you trying to \raisebox inside a sectional unit (like \section)?

both the \\  in your current code are wrong. you should never end a line that way outside environments such as tabular or array.
